# my xml and xsl doesn't show in google chrome but it does in other browsers why?

Tags: html, xslt, web, cross-browser

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html class="ie6 oldie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->

<!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<link href="menupage-main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</link>

<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</link>
<link href="food_menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</link>


<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #2D2C2C;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body,td,th {
    color: #F0E199;
}
</style>


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<DIV STYLE="background-image: url(background.jpg); background-size:200% 500%">

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">

<div id="header" class="fluid">

 <p align="center"><img src="header.jpg" alt="banner" width="100%" > </img></p>

  </div> </div>
```

This is part of my XSL code which has got html code in it which needs to work in Google chrome too. The xml data from this does not view in Google chrome for some reason. However it does in other browsers.

Comment: Fire up the Chrome developer tools using F12 and check the console for any error messages. Generally Chrome by default does not allow loading of XSLT from the file system so if you intend to deploy XML and XSLT on the server then test loading from that server, not from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an extension for Google Chrome like [XML Tree](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xml-tree/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb)

Comment: hello  need to it working without an extension as it will be on a server and it doesnt work on servers in general aswell im stuck  :/

Comment: @OmarFarooq If you cannot use an extension, there is still the source view of Chrome.